# Java: ApplicationImpl pooled while installing android studio on mac m1 monterey os

Tags: java, android-studio, apple-m1, macos-monterey

macOS monterey crashed while installing android studio after reset M1 where long logs details was generated. I tried installing android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 3 and Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 15.